# Get the same NSData of PHAsset after save

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset, phphotolibrary

Do you know is there any way to get the same NSData of Image ( JPG , PNG )  after save with `PHPhotoLibrary` or no?

OfC, iOS will modify some metadata and `EXIF`-- > ( Timestamp,... )data after save but, I'm asking about UIImage Data (**include same EXIF data**).
I didn't copy the exif in in my code here but it doesn't work
so Let's talk over the code:

**Save Image and get hash**

```
 UIImage * tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:tmpData];
 tmpData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmp, 1.0);
 self.str1 =  [tmpData MD5];                
 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
 PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *options = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
 options.originalFilename = @"XXX";
 PHAssetCreationRequest * createReq   =   [PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset];
[createReq  addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:tmpData options:options];
            } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"：%d",success);
 }];
```

Load same Image  :

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:0 completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput * _Nullable contentEditingInput,  NSDictionary * _Nonnull info) {
 PHImageRequestOptions * option = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
 option.synchronous = YES;
 option.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
 option.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
 option.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
 [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:option resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {


 UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 NSData * tmpDAt =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);           
 NSString * md5 =  [tmpDAt MD5];
 if ([md5 isEqualToString:self.str1]) {
  NSLog(@"My Expextation");
  }   
}];
```

The Intresting thing that I found is if I crop my image to `1*1` for test, I receive some error ( `JPEGDecompressSurface : Picture decode failed:` )  during save (It seems OS can't modify image) so I get the same hash before and after save :) !

Answer (score 0):

I presume the difference is due to your JPEGs having different timestamps (and possibly other differences) in their EXIF metadata.

Have you tried using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` instead of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`? Hopefully PNG representations will match.

Comment: I was thinking  about this too but what If I copy all of EXIF data for the new image ? (JPEG)

Comment: also, I tried with `UIImagePNGRepresentation` also as you know PNG doesn't keep the orientation so I check the md5 results in all orientation and doesn't match with the original one.
I think it can be related to timestamp and ... but not sure as I'm copy all of EXIF information for the new image

Answer (score 0):

Jpeg compression is a Lossy form of compression. Every time you convert to Jpeg you will lose data. There is no way around it. Removing PHPhotoLibrary from the equation. If you run the following

```
UIImage * tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:tmpData];
tmpData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmp, 1.0);
str1 =  [tmpData MD5];
tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:tmpData];
tmpData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmp, 1.0);
str2 =  [tmpData MD5];
```

You will find that str1 and str2 are different.

If you want the same data you will have to either keep the original jpeg data that generated the image or use a loseless compression method like the one used within the PNG files.